# Use $\sin^22t=4\sin^2t(1-\sin^2 t)$ to show that $\sin t$ is not a polynomial?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I am reading Barbeau's Polynomials and I found the following problem:

> Use the identity $\sin^22t=4\sin^2t(1-\sin^2 t)$ to show that $\sin t$ is not a polynomial.

But I really have no idea on how to do it, can you provide me some hint on what I should look in order to answer it?

Comment: Let $n$ be the degree of the polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\left(t\right)$ is a polynomial then $f\left(2t\right)^{2}$
has degree $2d$ and $4f\left(t\right)^{2}\left(1-f\left(t\right)^{2}\right)$
has degree $4d$.

If they are the same then $d=0$ i.e. $f$ is a
constant function. Function $\sin$ however is not constant.